# Node js wrap async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm implementing an API which has a function:

```
get(url)
```

Which returns a Response Object, i.e. no callback. The Http Modules I have found implements node-style async functions with callbacks. I have tried to wait for the async function to return in several ways, using Fibers etc. Fibers solves the issue within the Fiber, but can't be used in my case as I need to return the value outside any Fiber.

It might be possible to wrap the Entire Execution (including the code using the API) but I really don't want this. Is there any module that does what I want?

Comment: You can't use an asynchronous result as the return value from a function w/o a busy waiting hack.  Your `get` API method has to use a callback parameter or return a promise.

Comment: I really cant do that as Im implementing an API. Existing code expects this function to be synchronous. Could you expand on 'busy waiting hack'?

Comment: Why are you using Node if you're prohibited from using an async workflow?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, that you're trying to mix asynchronous code with synchronous code what you're trying to accomplish is not really possible without promises. As soon as you mix asynchronous code with synchronous code, you make the entire code asynchronous, or you risk the synchronous code returning a value before the result from the synchronous code is returned.

You could always try a timeout on the function that holds it returning until a given time period has expired, which hopes that the asynchronous code executes and has a return value before the synchronous code returns. However, this is extremely inefficient, and does not eliminate the problem as you could still end up returning before the asynchronous portion has finished.

I'd also agree with the comment from robertklep that node.js really does not fit your use case, and you might be better looking at another tool for the job.

Comment: As Im control the scope in which the API is used, I managed to wrap it in a fiber, letting be use run and yield inside the API functions.